# Presto - Ranger Issue with Hive Connector

Tags: hive, presto, cloudera-cdh, apache-ranger, starburst

We have a Presto(Version - 323-E.8) connector with Ranger enabled CDP Hive3 cluster where I'm able to run the select query on existing Hive ORC foramatted tables but couldn't create or delete any views on Hive metastore. It's throwing permissions issue error and my admin has granted all the permissions to the user from Ranger & AD and I'm able to perform all the operations from beeline with same user on the server.
Hive Properties:

```
*connector.name=hive-hadoop2
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://XXXXX
hive.views-execution.enabled=true
hive.metastore.authentication.type=KERBEROS
hive.metastore.service.principal=hive/_HOST@XXXX
hive.metastore.client.principal=XXXXX
hive.metastore.client.keytab=/abc/xxxx.keytab
hive.hdfs.wire-encryption.enabled=false
hive.metastore.thrift.impersonation.enabled=true
hive.config.resources=/etc/cdp/core-site.xml,/etc/cdp/hdfs-site.xml,/etc/cdp/hive-site.xml
hive.hdfs.authentication.type=KERBEROS
hive.hdfs.presto.principal=hdfs/_HOST@XXXXX
hive.hdfs.presto.principal=XXXX
hive.hdfs.presto.keytab=/abc/xxxx.keytab
hive.security=ranger
ranger.policy-rest-url=https://XXXXX:6182
ranger.service-name=cm_hive
ranger.authentication-type=KERBEROS
ranger.kerberos-principal=XXXX
ranger.kerberos-keytab=/abc/xxxx.keytab
ranger.plugin-policy-ssl-config-file=/abc/ssl-client.xml*
```

Error:
io.prestosql.spi.PrestoException: Operation type CREATE_VIEW not allowed for user:XXXXX
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftHiveMetastore.createTable(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1036)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.BridgingHiveMetastore.createTable(BridgingHiveMetastore.java:184)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.cache.CachingHiveMetastore.createTable(CachingHiveMetastore.java:524)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.cache.CachingHiveMetastore.createTable(CachingHiveMetastore.java:524)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.SemiTransactionalHiveMetastore$CreateTableOperation.run(SemiTransactionalHiveMetastore.java:2692)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.SemiTransactionalHiveMetastore$Committer.executeAddTableOperations(SemiTransactionalHiveMetastore.java:1668)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.SemiTransactionalHiveMetastore$Committer.access$1000(SemiTransactionalHiveMetastore.java:1282)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.SemiTransactionalHiveMetastore.commitShared(SemiTransactionalHiveMetastore.java:1225)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.SemiTransactionalHiveMetastore.commit(SemiTransactionalHiveMetastore.java:991)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.HiveMetadata.commit(HiveMetadata.java:2408)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.HiveConnector.commit(HiveConnector.java:202)
    at io.prestosql.transaction.InMemoryTransactionManager$TransactionMetadata$ConnectorTransactionMetadata.commit(InMemoryTransactionManager.java:595)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:57)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
    at io.airlift.concurrent.BoundedExecutor.drainQueue(BoundedExecutor.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException: Operation type CREATE_VIEW not allowed for user:XXXXX
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$create_table_result$create_table_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:52658)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$create_table_result$create_table_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:52626)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$create_table_result.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:52552)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_create_table(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.create_table(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1477)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.base.util.LoggingInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(LoggingInvocationHandler.java:60)
    at com.google.common.reflect.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy370.create_table(Unknown Source)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftHiveMetastoreClient.createTable(ThriftHiveMetastoreClient.java:161)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftHiveMetastore.lambda$createTable$51(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1024)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftMetastoreApiStats.lambda$wrap$0(ThriftMetastoreApiStats.java:42)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.util.RetryDriver.run(RetryDriver.java:130)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftHiveMetastore.createTable(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1022)
    ... 19 more

Comment: It seems related to Hive metastore integration with Presto. Can you please share your hive site xml file?

Comment: The `CREATE VIEW` is being rejected on the metastore side (`MetaException: Operation type CREATE_VIEW not allowed for user:XXXXX`). You should check the metastore logs.

Comment: BTW for this kind of troubleshooting problems, I recommend [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html)'s `#troubleshooting` channel.

Comment: Our admin has granted all the accesses through Ranger on Hive and HDFS , I'm able to run the select query on the existing tables, only the views creation is the issue.